# Need an explanation for a confusing way the AND boolean works

Tags: boolean

I am tutoring someone in basic search and sorts. In insertion sort I iterate negatively when I have a value that is greater than the one previous to it in numerical terms. Now of course this approach can cause issues because there is a check which calls for array[-1] which does not exist.

As underlined in bold below, adding the and x > 0 boolean prevents the index issue.

My question is how is this the case? Wouldn't the call for array[-1] still be made to ensure the validity of both booleans?

```
the_list = [10,2,4,3,5,7,8,9,6]

for x in range(1,len(the_list)):
    value = the_list[x]


    while value < the_list[x-1] **and x > 0**:

        the_list[x] = the_list[x-1]

        x=x-1

    the_list[x] = value

print the_list
```

Comment: According to the answers below most modern languages that pass through the 'and' statement will stop the moment one of the booleans does not meet the and condition. Unfortunately this  raises a secondary question, that being which boolean is evaluated first. As opposed to the ostensibly expected left to right approach it appears *python's* evaluation order is different. As such what now remains is to find documentation on the algorithm for this order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I *completely* understand the question, and I don't know what programming language this is, but most modern programming languages use so-called short-circuit Boolean evaluation by default so that the logical expression isn't evaluated further once the outcome is known.

You can use that to guard against range overflow, like this:

```
while x > 0 and value < the_list[x-1]
```

but the check of x's range here must come *before* the use.

Comment: This would seemingly be the case. The idea I had imagined was that the second the program say the *and* statement it would refer backwards to the booleans up until that point and check them. However in python it appears that reversing the order makes no difference. I should note that the language is python.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` operation returns `true` if and only if both arguments are true, so if one of arguments is false there's no point of checking others as the final value is already known at that point. As for your example, usually evaluation  goes from left to right but it is not a principle and it looks the language you used is not following that rule (othewise it still should crash on array lookup). But ut may be, this particular implementation optimizes this somehow (which IMHO is not good idea) and evaluates "simpler" things first (like checking if `x > 0`) before it look up the array. check the specs why this exact order works for you as in most popular languages you would still crash if test `x > 0` wouldn't be evaluated before lookup

Comment: Thank you, this is what I suspected however I am left wondering as to what the order of prioritization in regards to boolean resolution is.

Comment: I'd follow `left to right` order rule regardless of used language as for most cases that what you'd get. In this question, check specs of used language